# ¿Cómo hacer esta animación?

Tags: css, css3, scss

Buenas, ando buscando como puedo hacer en CSS la siguiente animación.

Tengo un Icono de user y un texto `Ingresar` en mi header, y lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer mouseover sobre ese icono salga desde la derecha hacia la izquierda el texto ingresar.

X = Icono User

Como se veria default:  ::Home:::::Contact:::::::::::::::::::::::X

Transicion: ::Home:::::Contact:::::::::::::::::::::::X<---Ingresar

Como se veria al pasar el mouse: ::Home:::::Contact:::::::::::::::::::::::X ingresar

```
  <div className="header-box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Comunidad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        <li className="account-btn"><a href="#"><Usericon /><div className="account-txt">Ingresar</div></a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente deseo que el texto ingresar solo aparezca cuando se hace mouseover sobre el icono

Aqui un video de lo que exactamente necesito

https://youtu.be/6jkyWBGuF9U

Comment: Ponte unas imágenes para entender mejor.

Comment: Por favor comparte el código CSS que llevas hasta ahora, y también procura añadir una imagen representativa.

Comment: Ya puse, siento haber omitido la imagen

Comment: Solo dale un `opacity: 0;` al texto y el `:hover` del padre, cámbiale de opacidad a `1`.

Comment: Si pero me gustaria que ese texto entre desde el costado con una animacion no que solo aparezca de la nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Me gustaria que ese texto entre desde el costado con una animacion no que solo aparezca de la nada.

Entonces usa translate también. En estado normal, pones la opacidad a 0 y mueves el texto hacia la derecha, sacándolo de vista:

```
.account-btn {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.account-btn .account-txt {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: translateX(150px);
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Los pixeles que mueves el texto depende de ti. Ahora, en hover del enlace cambias esas reglas:

```
.account-btn:hover .account-txt {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Ahora cuando hagas hover en el enlace, el texto vendrá desde la derecha con una animación y cambiando su opacidad.

#### Actualización

Acabo de ver el vídeo de tu actualización y lo que quieres es que el texto "empuje" el ícono. Similar a la forma anterior, debes jugar con `transform`.

**Ejemplo**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rationale');

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
 background-color: #313131;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
 padding: 8px 10px;
}

.account-btn {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}

.account-btn .account-txt {
  font-family: 'Rationale';
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .35s linear;
}

.account-btn i {
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition: all .35s linear;
}

.account-btn:hover .account-txt {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.account-btn:hover i {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<nav class="menu">
  <a class="account-btn">
    <i class="material-icons">person_outline</i>
    <label class="account-txt">Login</label>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: .account-txt {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.account-txt:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all .5s ease
}

Intente asi, pero el texto desaparece y no hace nada al pasar el mouse.

Comment: Es porque al que debes darle los estilos en hover es al padre (del ícono y del texto). Ya que inicialmente el texto desaparece, no te será posible poner el mouse sobre él.

Comment: Algo asi?

.account-btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all .5s ease
}

.account-txt {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.account-txt:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all .5s ease
}
Esto no funciono :(

Comment: Esto está bien: `.account-txt { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(150px); transition: all .5s ease; }`. Ahora, debes cambiar las propiedades del texto cuando el padre gane hover: `.account-btn:hover .account-txt { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); }`.

Comment: Funciona pero no hace una animacion, solo aparece el texto

Comment: No puede ser. Fíjate si has escrito bien las reglas css. Te digo esto porque transition hace un elemento animable y tanto opacity como transform son animables. Inspecciona el documento, selecciona el botón y mira que cosas cambian cuando gana hover.

Comment: No logro hacerlo bro xD te puedes conectar al skype luego?

Comment: Claro, mientras he editado mi respuesta para ponerte el código tal cual. Míralo y me avisas.

Comment: Gracias guz, funciona, pero mas especificamente lo que me gustaria es que en lugar de solo aparecer el texto animado y todo que digamos al pasar el mouse en el iconito el texto salga desde la derecha dgamos salga del borde de la pantalla y empuje el iconito y quede alli a su lado

Comment: Acabo de subir un video, seria eso del video pero que lo haga animado

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni He visto tu vídeo y he actualizado mi respuesta en base a el.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57658/discussion-between-santiago-dantuoni-and-gustavo-garcia).